# Update table values using 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion, oracle11g, coldfusion-9

I have 2 tables as follows:

COMMENT TEXT

```
RECORD_ID_FK   SORT_ORDER   COMMENT_TEXT
-----------------------------------------
 101             1           TEST TEXT
 101             1           SOME MORE TEST TEXT
 101             1           SOME MORE...
 101             2           SOME MORE...
 101             2           SOME MORE...
 101             2           SOME MORE...
 101             2           SOME MORE...
 101             3           SOME MORE...
 101             3           SOME MORE...
 101             3           SOME MORE...
 102             1           TEST TEXT
 102             1           SOME MORE TEST TEXT
 102             1           SOME MORE...
 102             2           SOME MORE...
 102             2           SOME MORE...
 102             2           SOME MORE...
 102             2           SOME MORE...
 102             3           SOME MORE...
 102             3           SOME MORE...
 102             3           SOME MORE...
```

PRODUCTS

```
 PRODUCT_ID      SORT_ORDER   RECORD_ID_FK
 -----------------------------------------
 111             1             101
 222             2             101
 333             3             101
 444             1             102
 555             2             102
 666             3             102
```

I need to be able to change the sort order of the comments from values supplied by a form.
Any SORT_ORDER entry in the comments table can be swapped around, so all SORT_ORDER value 3 can be swapped to value 2, or all SORT_ORDER value 1's can be swapped for value 2 and value 2 can be swapped with value 3 etc etc.

The function where the update sql will reside excepts the SORT_ORDER and a PRODUCT_ID value and is hit each time via a loop in an action file.

I have tried this by using an sql update statement and using EXISTS() so looking to see if the PRODUCT_ID exists and joining the RECORD_ID and SORT_ORDER but this fails as soon as the SORT_ORDER is changed the next row to change fails as the SORT_ORDER is no longer valid.

I don't think this is acheivable with what I have here, as I am limited to how I can link the 2 tables to change the SORT_ORDER en masse.

I am using Oracle 11g and Coldfusion 9.

Any ideas would be greatly appeciated or confirmation that this is not actually possible with what I have here.

Thanks

JC

Comment: Any entry in *which* table can be swapped around? Is there a `product_id` column on `comment_text` - otherwise how do you have different `sort_order` values for the same `record_id_fk`? Seems like something is missing from this picture. You might need to show before/after data. Also not sure why you're storing/updating the `sort_order` in two tables, rather than joining to get the current value at runtime?

Comment: I have amended my text regarding: Any entry in which table can be swapped around. No there isn't a product id in the comments table otherwise it would be an easier case to solve. I'm stuck with this design unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure how the `product` table fits in then. Just swapping the values in `comments_text` is fairly easy... oh, so you only swap those in the `comments_text` table with a `record_id_fk` linked to the passed `product_id`? (And the `product.sort_order` isn't relevant here?) You also said you're passed *a* `sort_order`, so how do you know what to swap that with?

Comment: Is record_id_fk a foreign key to another table?  If so, can you apply the sort order to that table?

Comment: How about you get the row_id (a pseudo-column which stores the address of a row in Oracle) and use that as your unique identifier while updating the data?